# How to react to a onclick in an ultragrid

Tags: c#, events, onclick, mouseevent, infragistics

I have code that creates an UltraGrid with a column that has the `ColumnStyle.Button` as it's style.

```
   private void Grid_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e){
        Grid.ResetEmptySelectedAppearance();

        var column =  Grid.SetColumn("Draw Lines", "Draw Lines", 30);
        column.Style = ColumnStyle.Button;

        Grid.HideOtherColumns();
    }
```

Now I would like too make it react to being clicked on. I have found [this](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~ClickCellButton_EV.html) but it does not show me how to bind the variable, usually I can either double click in the visual studio editor (but in this case this only directs me too the `Grid_InitializeLayout`) or I can go the the item in question and add the function to an `OnClick` variable, but this one doesn't exist.

```
private void Grid_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
        var buttoncell= e.Row.Cells["Draw Lines"];
        //something here?
```

this is what I want to call

```
   private void OnDrawLine(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("test test");
    }
```

It's probably something trivial but I'm stuck.

Comment: The code is quite complex so if anything more is needed please ask, or if there is someway I can otherwise add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UltraGrid` responds to clicks on a cell button as explained in the link posted using an event called `ClickCellButton`. You need to subscribe to this grid event in the usual ways. (Designer or code doesn't matter)

```
private void Grid_ClickCellButton(object sender, ClickCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the click happens on the required column
    if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "Draw Lines")
    {
        ... your code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I missed that it was in Grid and called ClickCellButton, I looked for thing containing Button in the cells and anything with on in it in the grid but didn't check bothm thanks!